# getting duplicate messages on consumer

Tags: go, apache-kafka

I have started 4 consumers with this config, sometimes the same message receives by multiple consumers.

I have added `GroupID` to prevent duplicates

Kafka lib: https://github.com/segmentio/kafka-go

```
consumer := kafka.NewReader(kafka.ReaderConfig{
        Brokers:         kafkaBrokers,
        Topic:             "my-topic",
        StartOffset:     kafka.FirstOffset,
        MinBytes:        1,
        MaxBytes:        100e6,
        GroupID:          "my-group",
        MaxWait:         time.Hour * 24,
        ReadLagInterval: 1 * time.Second,
        Dialer:          dialer,
        QueueCapacity:   queueCapacity * 2,
    })
```

Comment: If the offsets are unique, they aren't duplicates. Can you show us them?

Comment: @OneCricketeer yes I am getting duplicate messages with the same offset value

Comment: Your config seems fine. What's your poll look like? Do you get the same with Sarama or Confluent go client?

Comment: Do the broker logs show the consumers getting rebalanced ?